# How can I increase the number of bots in Section 8?

Tags: section-8

I heard it can be done using unreal engine console commands.

But what commands should I use?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by executing admin commands on a dedicate server.

> After you have logged in as the administrator, admin commands can be issued using the virtual keyboard.
>
> To issue an admin command:
>
> 1. Open the virtual keyboard through the in-game menu by pressing the START
>       buttonstart and selecting "ENTER ADMIN COMMAND".
> 2. Type “Admin Command” in the virtual keyboard where "Command" 
>       is the command you wish to execute.
>
>    Ex: admin changemap des10_base-smalla

For what you want, you need to execute `AddBot` command:

> - AddBot [TeamName]
>     Adds a bot to the team named [TeamName]
>     Ex: Addbot Section 8
>     **Note**: AddBot is only available when bot mode is set to None
> - AddBot [TeamID]
>     Adds a bot to the team with index [TeamID]; 0 is Section 8, 1 is Arm
>     **Note**: AddBot is only available when bot mode is set to None
> - RemoveBot [TeamName]
>     Removes a bot from the team named [TeamName]
>     Ex: Removebot Arm
>     **Note**: RemoveBot is only available when bot mode is set to None
> - RemoveBot [TeamID]
>     Removes a bot from the team with index [TeamID]; 0 is Section 8, 1 is ARM
>     **Note**: RemoveBot is only available when bot mode is set to None

Source: [Section 8(TM) TGNServer English (North America) version 1.1 Readme](http://support.timegate.com/attachment_files.php?s=e297a364735c45cffd530357208b2390&id=13)

Comment: how do i login as admin? i am actually just playing single player for now, on a single computer. please also specify what password i may need to use?

Comment: @jie, I don't know if you can do it without a dedicated server. Did you try using those commands in the console?

Comment: i tried addbot section 8 they said i must login as admin 1st

Comment: @jie, try "Admin addbot section 8" -- read the read me I linked in the body of the post and search for "5.3 EXECUTING ADMIN COMMANDS"